# Temp Converter Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, converters, temperature

I created this temp converter in JavaScript, it runs and calculates appropriately, but I am receiving some "unexpected behavior" and I'm struggling to understand why its happening.

The behavior that is happening is  if I click in the Celsius or Fahrenheit textbox it auto produces values: -32 in Celsius textbox, and 32 in Fahrenheit textbox. Once I remove one of the auto produced values from the textbox, it will convert appropriately like so:

100C it converts to 212F and  if you enter 32F it converts to 0C.

This part is more of a bonus to see if I could convert from all 3 temp measurements Fahrenheit, Celsius, and Kelvin. It doesn't convert if you enter a value in Fahrenheit or Celsius textbox, but if you input a number directly into Kelvin textbox it will convert  to the other 2 measurements coorectly.

Will I need a loop, or control statement to add Kelvin appropriately to this program?

the form tags name is "converter"  Here's the code:

```
function toCelsius() {
  document.converter.fahrenheit.value =(document.converter.celsius.value * 9/5) + 32;
}

function toFahrenheit() {
    document.converter.celsius.value = (document.converter.fahrenheit.value *5/9) -32;
}

function toKelvin(){
    document.converter.celsius.value = document.converter.kelvin.value - 273.15;
    document.converter.fahrenheit.value=((document.converter.kelvin.value - 273.15)*9/5)+32;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the full code that is doing this? either here or using jsfiddle.net

Comment: Your algorithm for fahrenheit to celsius is wrong, it should be `(fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9`. Similarly for *toKelvin*. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formulas are:

```
°F = °C x 9/5 + 32
°C = (°F - 32) x 5/9
```

so:

```
function toFahrenheit() {
  document.converter.celsius.value = (document.converter.fahrenheit.value - 32) * 5 / 9;
}
```

As for the bonus question, I think you need to attach a handler function to each of the 3 `input` elements (assuming you are using those) and synchronize the other values accordingly. No need for a loop. Something like this:

```
<input id='c' type="number" onchange="converter_function('c', this.value)" />°C
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teyw4tah/2/

For the purists:

http://jsfiddle.net/teyw4tah/3/

Comment: I would recommed not teaching `onchange` attributes as they require creating global values and your webpage will very quickly become an unmaintainable mess. Instead use the `addEventListener` to attach properly scoped functions.

Comment: I agree but I wanted to keep it as simple as possible

Comment: Thanks  for your responses and clarity.  Thanks for keeping it simple.  I'm just starting off in Javascript so I don't know how to handle events yet.  I have experience with c#.  I imagine handling objects is different in Javascript?